# Culture Specific Date Time in Javascript

Tags: jquery, format, datetimepicker, culture

Hi I am using Jquery's DateTimePicker plugin in my ASP.Net we site. I want to have culture specific date format for my date time picker and where ever date is displayed from JavaScript should also be culture specific. How can we read culture/ regional settings in JavaScript. Also I need both Date and Time.

My Code

```
 $('#datetimepicker_mask1').datetimepicker({
   **format: 'd/m/Y H:i'**, onSelectTime: function (dp, $input) {}});
```

As I am harcoding the date format of datetimepicker, I want this format to be dynamic, as date time settings of the system where the site is being viewed

Comment: Are you talking about [`new Date().toLocaleString();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) ?

Comment: can you please elaborate what is culture specific? Also show us your jquery datepickere code .

Answer (score 0):

The Date() object will get you the client time

```
var now=new Date();
alert(now.toLocaleString());
```

JS and jQuery don't have a built in format function. To format it differently use a function like format():

```
var now=new Date();    
alert( now.format("dd/mm/yy h:MM:ss TT") );
```

For more deatils of formate() visit [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).

You can also